# How dynamic android application works?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I know how to design and develop android application which works offline.But now i want to move towards dynamic android app,which works totally online like facebook,quora,newshunt.Where should i start please give me  a way.
Thanks

Comment: It could be better to use word "online" instead of "dynamic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally am completely self-taught when it comes to android, and, well, its been a journey.

For me, a big turning point was

"http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/"

It really gives you a good idea of what it takes to create an app that is connected to the internet, and it isn't hard to implement yourself. Mind you, before, you were working with just android, but once you integrate network connectivity and a server backend, the levels of complexity multiply.

If you're a solo-developer, just getting started, the Google App Engine does a pretty good job of making everything very easy to use, so I might recommend that. It has a free trial of all their cloud services which is $300 for 2 months.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine

Amazon AWS also is attempting to create a similar system, but they are seemingly geared to more enterprise-level operations.

Comment: what topic should i learn first i.e should i learn php-mysql first or html parser or json or jsoup,,i am just confused where to start?

Comment: There is so, so, soooooo much to learn. This is an entire industry after all. You can never  know it all. 

It's best to just start with what you want to do and go from there.

So, what do you want to do?

Comment: @SiddharthChandra You should first get familiar with Android main building blocks, especially Activities and Services and then its better off to learn a server side technology.

Comment: I just want to make an app which will fetch data from its server and show it in the app,where should i start?

Comment: What kind of data are you looking to fetch?  Just little strings? Small images? High quality videos?

Start with what kind of content you're delivering, and how you intend to deliver it.